# jQuery.Keyframes undefined isSupported

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, css-animations, keyframe

I'm trying to change an animation via the jQuery.Keyframes library (https://github.com/Keyframes/jQuery.Keyframes), but for "var supportedFlag = $.keyframe.isSupported();", isSupported is undefined. I correctly called the JS in my html, however I changed "http" to 'https "for the jQuery.Keyframes library. [HTML code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j3T4X.png)

```js
$(function(){

    //Background
    var white = $('.white');
    var green = $('.green');
    var supportedFlag = $.keyframe.isSupported();

    $('.green').hover(
        //Handle In
        function(){     
            $.keyframe.define([{
                name: 'slide',
                '0%': {
                    'transform' : 'translateX(-23%)'
                },
                '100%': {
                    'transform' : 'translateX(-19%)'
                }
            }]);
            white.css('visibility', 'hidden');
        },
        //Handle Out
        function(){
            $.keyframe.define([{
                name: 'slide',
                '0%': {
                    'transform' : 'translateX(-2%)'
                },
                '100%': {
                    'transform' : 'translateX(2%)'
                }
            }]);
            white.css('visibility', 'visible');
        }
    );
    $('.white').hover(
        //Handle In
        function(){     
            $.keyframe.define([{
                name: 'slide',
                '0%': {
                    'transform' : 'translateX(23%)'
                },
                '100%': {
                    'transform' : 'translateX(19%)'
                }
            }]);
            green.css('visibility', 'hidden');

        },
        //Handle Out
        function(){
            $.keyframe.define([{
                name: 'slide',
                '0%': {
                    'transform' : 'translateX(-2%)'
                },
                '100%': {
                    'transform' : 'translateX(2%)'
                }
            }]);
            green.css('visibility', 'visible');
        }
    );
});
```

[Error code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vjhUN.png)

What to do to resolv this problem ?
Thank you !

Comment: Basically it means that plugin `$.keyframe` is not available at that time. Did you try to to wait for the document to be ready - e.g. `$(document).ready(function() { ... })`?

Comment: I tried, but same. I have already the "$(function)" to ensure that the document is ready.

Comment: You're right, I missed that... I could not find the KeyFrame lib explicitly in the HTML screenshot you've added. Doing it similar to https://github.com/Keyframes/jQuery.Keyframes/blob/master/example/index.html should work.
`$.keyframe` not being available basically means it's loaded too late or not at all.

Comment: Yeah. I did not understand that it was necessary to install another script. I installed the src, but it didn't work. Then I tried with the dist, and it worked. Thank you Oliver for your help !